Template format error: Unrecognized resource types: [AWS::CloudFormation::Hook]
cloudformation stacks
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
LambdaFunctionInvokerHook:
Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Hook
Properties:
TypeName: AWSSamples::LambdaFunctionInvoker::Hook
Description: AWS CloudFormation hook that invokes AWS Lambda functions you specify for proactive policy-as-code compliance validation checks.
TypeConfiguration:
LambdaFunctions:
- arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:aacount_id:function:function_name
But the stack is generating errors while both the resources exist, could you please guide me through the corrections?
Template format error: Unrecognized resource types: [AWS::CloudFormation::Hook]
Template format error: Unrecognized resource types: [AWSSamples::LambdaFunctionInvoker::Hook]

Where in aws docs did you find AWS::CloudFormation::Hook?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
